# How to redirect all pages in my mvc asp.net web app except for one role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I work with asp.net c# mvc framework. I need a way to 'turn-off' my web app for all users except administrator (i. e. all pages should return to something like "The application is closed" for all the roles except Admin).

I already create a button in order to save the status of the web app (ON/OFF) in a DB.

Do I have to check on each page the status of the application ?
Is-it possible to have a global redirection except for one role ?

I don't know how to properly do this global closure. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: you can make custom filter attributes and check for authentication there..

Comment: Or create a base Pageclass containing the functionality and derive all pages from this base. This way you only write it once.

Comment: You can create a base controller that you inherit, which has a custom attribute that does the lock checking for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your requirement with the help of custom filters shown below :-

```
  [CheckUserRole]
  public class YourController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {

    }
  }

 public class CheckUserRoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       // Get the User Id from the session
       // Get Role associated with the user (probably from database)
       // Get the permission associated with the role (like Read, write etc)

       // if user is not authenticated then do as :

         filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
         RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I can think of three approaches to check and do a redircet

1. An [`HttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hooked into the appropriate, post-authorisation event. Presumably [`PostAuthorizeRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthorizerequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of [`HttpApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpApplication(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. In your "global" (`Global.aspx.cs`) subscribe to that same event.
3. An MVC Action filter, overriding [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx). (Ensure you make it global, to avoid needing to apply to every controller: add to [`GlobalFilters.Filters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.globalfilters.filters%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in your `Application_Start`.)

Of these 3 is part of MVC, but is much later in the pipeline (much more work will have been done, to be thrown away when the filter fails).

Use of a module is controlled by configuration which would make is easier to switch on and off.

option 2 is likely easiest to implement, but I would tend to prefer the modularity that 1 gives.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try[ActionFilterAttribute](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) ?

Here is a basic example:

Your controller:

```
[IsAdmin]
public class YourController
{

}
```

Your attribute

```
 public class IsAdminAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if ()  // Check that your user is not an Admin and that your application is "turn-off"
         { 
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403); // or whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Add [IsAdmin] on top of all your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

You can write in all other Controllers which are used as follows..

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) 
           return RedirectToAction("PagetoRedirect");
        else
           return RedirectToAction("CommonPagetoShowApplicationAsClosed");
    }
}
```

Or

[Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can create on your own and look for named action like `IndexRolename`

Comment: This will lead to writing the same logic multiple times, and violate the DRY principle.